# Extension method does not respect My.Application.Culture

Tags: vb.net, winforms, culture

In a VB.NET 4.72 WinForms project, i have placed an MDI form (MDIForm1), an MDIChild form (Form1) and a module. In the module, i have declared an extension method:

```
   <Extension()>
    Public Sub ShowChild(SourceForm As Form)
        MessageBox.Show(My.Application.Culture.ToString)
    End Sub
```

In the MDIForm's Load event, i have the following code:

```
    My.Application.ChangeCulture(NewCultureName)
    My.Application.ChangeUICulture(NewCultureName)
    'NewCultureName is a string which is set to any valid value other than "en-US".
    Form1.ShowChild
```

When debugging the project, the MessageBox that appears when ShowChild is called, displays "en-US" instead of the value of NewCultureName. If a breakpoint is placed in "Form1.ShowChild" statement, i can see that the culture has indeed changed to the value of NewCultureName. The application acts though as if there are two different instances of My.Application, one in the MDI form and another inside ShowChild. Why is this happening?

2019-04-14: Edited to a more precise description of the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what the Module extension is supposed to do or what is actually doing (it looks like just a proof-of-concept as it is now) , but you have to set both the thread culture - as you're doing now - and the UI culture: add `My.Application.ChangeUICulture("someother-Culture")` to `My.Application.ChangeCulture("someother-Culture")`.

Comment: It might also happen that the specified culture is not recognized as valid. Since you have that code in the Load event of a Form, the exception is not (visibly) thrown. Try `My.Application.ChangeCulture("hip-HOP")`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Jimmi. I have updated the OP in order to be more precise. The extension is indeed a proof-of-concept in this example. In the real application, it has a more important meaning. Even in this simple example though, the unexpected behaviour exists.

Comment: You should show your actual code, then. Maybe, you have created a new thread somewhere. As the post is now, it won't reproduce the issue. Also, `NewCultureName` has no indication of its content. I'm not saying it's wrong, it simply can't be seen.